# Hide sub menu when empty - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a main menu and a sub page menu - See here for example: http://www.healthwatchleicester.co.uk/newwebsite/find-services/ you will see the child elements from the main menu items listed in the left hand column as a sub menu. The code used for this is:

```
<div class="sub-page-menu">

      <div class="left-sidebar-title">
        <h4>
          <?php
          echo empty( $post->post_parent ) ? get_the_title( $post->ID ) : get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
          ?>
        </h4>
      </div>

      <?php
      wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'sub_menu' => true
      ) );
      ?>

    </div>
```

This seems to be working, but I would like this whole sub menu to disappear if it returns no child items...

I found this bit of code that seems along the right track but I'm afraid I don't know how it relates or even if its correct...

```
<?php
$menu = wp_nav_menu(
array (
    'echo' => FALSE,
    'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
)
);

if ( ! empty ( $menu ) )
{
echo '<div class="navmain2">' . $menu . '</div>';
}
?>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yup, so this should work:

```
<div class="sub-page-menu">

<?php

$menu = wp_nav_menu(
    array (
        'echo' => FALSE,
        'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
    )
);

if ( ! empty ( $menu ) )
{

?>

    <!-- move anything else you need to hide between here -->

    <div class="left-sidebar-title">
        <h4>
        <?php
            echo empty( $post->post_parent ) ? get_the_title( $post->ID ) : get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
        ?>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <!-- and here -->

<?php

    echo $menu;

}

?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @sergchernata... Please see the comment below - It was directed at you but it wouldn't let me tag you in a comment...

Comment: You should delete that comment, you posted it as an answer. I edited my answer with a tip on what to do.

Comment: Oops!! I did that because the comments section wasn't big enough for the followup question... Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Ok, this is still not working - I've tried it on a new website... I'm going to post another question :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You also need to merge the arguments from your first solution with the solution you found:

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu(
    array (
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'sub_menu' => true,
        'echo' => FALSE,
        'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
    )
);

if (!empty($menu)) {
    // a menu exists, so output menu html
}
```

To explain why it works:

- Setting the `echo` argument to `FALSE` makes the `wp_nav_menu` function return a string.
- Setting the `fallback_cb` to the function `__return_false` makes the `wp_nav_menu` function not fallback to a default menu when a primary menu doesn't exist. It should return a falsey value instead (e.g. an empty string).
- If the `$menu` variable is a falsey value, then you don't need to output anything.